# memory consumption at encoding base64

Tags: go, base64, out-of-memory, pprof

I have problems with memory consumption at my software using golangs lib encoding/base64

My software is splitting a videofile to separate images, (gocv mat)
converting them to base64 string and saving it to file in json format.

During testing I found that the memory usage is piling up until
the oom-reaper is killing the process.

Investigation with pprof showed that the encoding/base64 memory seems to pile up.

I did pprof snapshots after each image frame, and allocated mem of
encoding/base64 is raising from 976.89kB(flat) to 4633.54kB(flat) shortly before oom-reaper was killing the process.

```
Beginning:
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  976.89kB 32.29% 32.29%   976.89kB 32.29%  encoding/base64.(*Encoding).EncodeToString
  512.50kB 16.94% 49.23%   512.50kB 16.94%  runtime.allocm
  512.20kB 16.93% 66.15%   512.20kB 16.93%  runtime.malg
  512.05kB 16.92% 83.08%  1488.94kB 49.21%  runtime.main
     512kB 16.92%   100%      512kB 16.92%  time.resetTimer (inline)
         0     0%   100%   976.89kB 32.29%  main.Process

End:
Showing nodes accounting for 6170.44kB, 100% of 6170.44kB total
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
 4633.54kB 75.09% 75.09%  4633.54kB 75.09%  encoding/base64.(*Encoding).EncodeToString
 1024.41kB 16.60% 91.69%  1024.41kB 16.60%  runtime.malg
  512.50kB  8.31%   100%   512.50kB  8.31%  runtime.allocm
         0     0%   100%  4633.54kB 75.09%  main.Process
```

list shows me the code acoording to it:

```
(pprof) list encoding/base64
Total: 2.95MB
ROUTINE ======================== encoding/base64.(*Encoding).EncodeToString in /usr/local/go/src/encoding/base64/base64.go
  976.89kB   976.89kB (flat, cum) 32.29% of Total
         .          .    175:
         .          .    176:// EncodeToString returns the base64 encoding of src.
         .          .    177:func (enc *Encoding) EncodeToString(src []byte) string {
         .          .    178:   buf := make([]byte, enc.EncodedLen(len(src)))
         .          .    179:   enc.Encode(buf, src)
  976.89kB   976.89kB    180:   return string(buf)
         .          .    181:}
         .          .    182:
         .          .    183:type encoder struct {
         .          .    184:   err  error
         .          .    185:   enc  *Encoding
```

So in my golang code the according line of code was:

```
func Process(img gocv.Mat) ( myImage Images  ){

    detectImg, detectClass, detectBoxes := Detect(&net, 
                                           img.Clone(), 
                                           0.45, 0.5, 
                                           OutputNames, classes)
    defer detectImg.Close()

    // convert gocv.Mat to []bytes
    myImg , _ := detectImg.ToImage()
    myJPG := new(bytes.Buffer)
    jpeg.Encode(myJPG, myImg, &jpeg.Options{95})
    myBytes := myJPG.Bytes()


    // memory consuming
    encodedString := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(myBytes)

// [...]

    return myImage

}
```

How can I release the memory of "encodedString" in this case that it does not pile up?
(Update: Answers say this is not necessary and not possible)

Or is it maybe not my wrong coding, and the mem-leak is at the lib base64 ??
(Update: Answers say this is surely not the case)

Comment: That’s not showing you a memory leak, that’s just showing where allocations are made. You are not leaking the encodedString value, nor is there a leak in the base64 library.

Comment: Thanks JimB, but why is the value of allocated memory going up from 900k to 4500k ? For me this seems to be not regular behaviour..

Comment: regarding the feedback I update the title from memory leak to memory consumption

Comment: Seeing how you are using a Go wrapper around opencv, the memory you are concerned with is probably not even allocated by Go. In that case you _do_ need to ensure that everything is probably closed or released according to their documentation, because the bulk of the work is done in C++, not Go. Even if you are cleaning up properly however, you still need to be aware of your memory limitations and ensure you are not trying to hold too much data at any given point.

Comment: @JimB Thanks a lot, this is a very valuable hint! The memory debugging with pprof was only showing mem usage of some MB, while the real mem-consumption was going up much more, in GB area.. I will now investigate all the c-wrapper libs like gocv and gosseract.. I'm quite sure that you are right, Great help, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My question above was at a totaly wrong way.

Base64 was not at all the problem, it was just the top-consumer of memory
displayed at pprof, leading me to the faulty conclusion that base64 is the problem.

I guessed that pprof would tell me all mem-consumption
of my go programm, including gocv.
gocv is a c wrapper around opencv, but the mem-consumption of it is not visible to pprof, as it is c-code! (I did not know that at asking the question).
The memory consumption that was visible due pprof was not showing
the used memory by c-wrapper libs for go like gocv.
The big part of memory consumption was not visible to golang at all.
So the helping hint of JimB was:

> Seeing how you are using a Go wrapper around opencv, the memory you
> are concerned with is probably not even allocated by Go. In that case
> you do need to ensure that everything is probably closed or released
> according to their documentation, because the bulk of the work is done
> in C++, not Go. Even if you are cleaning up properly however, you
> still need to be aware of your memory limitations and ensure you are
> not trying to hold too much data at any given point.

As I was cleaning up the gocv objects, mem consumtion was going down significantly. I used to close objects:

```
defer obj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> How can I release the memory of "encodedString" in this case that it does not pile up?

You cannot and you need not. Unused memory is "freed".

> Or is it maybe not my wrong coding, and the mem-leak is at the lib base64 ?

No, package encoding/base64 has no memory leak. (Chances are 0 that you detect a memory leak in a trivial function in the standard library of a garbage collected language.)

To guide you towards a solution:

Your application *uses* absurd amount of memory but that's because a) processing video and images *is* memory hungry and b) you seem to do nothing to keep memory low: E.g. you encode the whole image into a bytes.Buffer, then encode the whole bytes.Buffer to a string then work on that string and so on. You probably should encode the image into a *stream*, encode this *stream* to base64 and *stream* this output further to where it deposited. This is totally painless in Go as all these encoders work on io.Writers which can be chained very easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Volker !