# memory leak debugging at golang code using c-wrapper gocv

Tags: c++, opencv, go, memory-leaks, wrapper

I was trying to memory-debug my golang code with pprof,
but I also use gocv, a wrapper around opencv (c++).
I was told that the mem-profiling with pprof is not showing me
the memory allocated by those wrappers.

> Seeing how you are using a Go wrapper around opencv, the memory you
> are concerned with is probably not even allocated by Go. In that case
> you do need to ensure that everything is probably closed or released
> according to their documentation, because the bulk of the work is done
> in C++, not Go. Even if you are cleaning up properly however, you
> still need to be aware of your memory limitations and ensure you are
> not trying to hold too much data at any given point.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70863870/memory-consumption-at-encoding-base64)

Question:
Is there a way to do memory profiling (like at golang with pprof) that includes also this c++ wrapped part with gocv of the golang-code ??

Doing it by hand (proper cleanup) was not helping me here, I guess I didn't found some code leaking memory..

Comment: Do you have a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: here are many examples of golang code using wrappers: https://gocv.io/writing-code/more-examples/

Comment: I meant an example of code that you believe to have a memory leak but where you can't find the leak, rather than simply an example of golang code that uses wrappers.   Please see this stack overflow help page on how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).